# DNS set correctly but website unreachable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, dns, iptables

I have the (sub)domain elo.bernardinuscollege.nl, which has a DNS A record that points to 54.225.118.87, which is correct (checked it with `telnet`, which indeed returns the right IP). For some reason though, I can't connect with my website via the domain (seems to cause some sort of timeout), while using the IP to access the website just works fine. Pinging to the IP works too, but pining the domain results in timeouts.

Same happens when trying to connect with FTP, so it seems like it is not a web server problem. Could Ubuntu or any kind of firewall be the problem?

Iptables is empty on the server. Trying to access the site via my own PC by adding the appropriate rule to my local hosts works, which really astonishes me.

My specs:

- Hosting: Amazon EC2
- OS: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-36-virtual x86_64)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DNS record is returning:  54.**255**.118.87 instead of 54.**225**.118.87

Here is my `nslookup` output

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   elo.bernardinuscollege.nl
Address: 54.255.118.87
```

Comment: Unbelievable I missed that... I might after all be dyslectic. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in dns setup. the second octal is incorrect, should be 225, not 255 as shown.

```
$ telnet elo.bernardinuscollege.nl 80
Trying 54.255.118.87...
```